# What exactly does the npm config "node-version" do?

Tags: node.js, npm

I mixed up *npm* config **node-version**  e.g in `.npmrc` file

```js
// .npmrc
node-version=14.17.0
```

...with *nvm* config file i.e. force `nvm` to use a node version

```js
// .nvmrc
v14.17.0
```

Which got me wondering - what does node-version do?

> **node-version**
>
> - Default: Node.js process.version value
> - Type: SemVer string
>
> The node version to use when checking a package's engines setting.

The docs read line its used to compare against the engine field

a. That seems weird

b. Yarn (at least) just checks using the currently active version of node